# Как создать программу с отгадыванием числа?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Когда я только знакомился с программированием, мне брат подкинул exe самописной программы. Исходники он потерял, а я хочу воссоздать эту программу.

Её суть такова:

Даётся три столбца с рандомными цифрами. Ты загадываешь одну цифру и вводишь номер столбца в котором она находится. Потом появляются ещё три столбца, с этими же номерами, но разбросанными по другому. Опять выбираешь столбец в котором твой номер. И так ещё раз. А дальше программа угадывает цифру которую ты загадал.
В общем я не представляю как это реализовать. Я знаю что это абсолютно примитивная консольная программа, но я ещё учусь :)

Дайте хоть какие-нибудь зацепки: алгоритм, пример кода, ссылки. Всему буду благодарен.

Comment: Если N столбцов по N цифр, то все очень просто - надо на втором ходу столбцы вывести построчно. Число определяется однозначно :)

Comment: Это массив с переменной switch. Если удобнее, то if else

Comment: Есть аналогичный карточный фокус - "http://ru.m.wikihow.com/показать-карточный-фокус-с-использованием-математики" Может поможет в реализации)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Дано 3 столбца и 3 итерации. Вариантов размещения одного числа так, что бы можно было по размещению определить число - девять: 000 (число всегда на месте), 001, 002, 010, 011, 012, 020, 021, 022.

Берем по 9 чисел для каждой колонки. Можем заполнить массив из 27 элементов случайными, уникальными числами. Далее в описании алгоритма под *число* будем понимать его позицию в этом массиве, начиная с 0. *Колонки* "на экране" будем нумеровать 0, 1, 2. На первой итерации первые 9 чисел заносим в 0 *колонку*, вторые - в 1ю, третьи в 2ю. При размещении на второй итерации берем остаток до деления *числа* на 9 (по сути это номер *числа* в своей группе первой итерации). Делим этот остаток нацело на 3 - это на сколько *колонок* надо сдвинуть число на второй итерации относительно изначального положения (`смещение = (X % 9) / 3`). Если номер первоначальной *колонки* + смещение больше 2, то начинаем отсчет с начала (т.е. делаем `2-(K1+смещение)`) На третьей итерации берем остаток от деления на 3 (`смещение=X % 3`). При таком походе мы для каждого *числа* получим расстановки указанные в самом начале поста.

Отгадывание: Номер колонки первой итерации умножаем на 9, прибавляем номер колонки второй итерации умноженный на 3, прибавляем номер колонки третьей итерации (`K1*9+K2*3+K3`). Все, получили *число* (ну т.е. его позицию в начальном массиве).

Пример:

```
1я итерация    2я итерация    3я итерация
0   1   2      0   1   2      0   1   2

0   9  18      0   3   6      0   1   2
1  10  19      1   4   7      3   4   5
2  11  20      2   5   8      6   7   8
3  12  21      9  12  15      9  10  11
4  13  22     10  13  16     12  13  14
5  14  23     11  14  17     15  16  17
6  15  24     18  21  24     18  19  20
7  16  25     19  22  25     21  22  23
8  17  26     20  23  26     24  25  26
```

Пользователь ввел: 2-я, 1-я, 0-я: `2*9+1*3+0=21`,  ввел 1-я, 2-я, 1-я: `1*9+2*3+1=16`

Содержимое колонок на каждой итерации можно перемешать, что бы не было видно закономерностей в распределении.

Прямая печать индексов исходного массива на php (формулы пересмотрены для случая печати всех трех итераций в строку, как на примере выше):

```
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++) {   // Строка
 for($j=0;$j<3;$j++) {  // Итерация
  for($k=0;$k<3;$k++) { // Колонка
   if($j==0)     $m=$i+9*$k;
   elseif($j==1) $m=(int)($i/3)*9+$i%3+$k*3;
   else          $m=$i*3+$k;
   printf("%3d",$m);
  }
  print "  ";
 }
 print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Без вас я бы ни за что не догадался.
Кстати этот алгоритм, можно где-нибудь о нём почитать (есть ли статья в Wiki, как он вообще называется)? Или это вы сами его придумали? :)

Comment: Просто, если честно, я не до конца понял что значат эти варианты размещения _000 (число всегда на месте), 001, 002, 010, 011, 012, 020, 021, 022._

Comment: Посмотрите на таблицу. Числа 0, 13 и 26 во всех трех случаях в одной и той же колонке. В каждой колонке по 1 такому числу - это 000. Числа 1, 14, 24 первые два раза в своей колонке, последний раз в следующей - это 001. Обратите внимание на "следующую" колонку у числа 24 - оно должно было бы переместится вправо и попасть в несуществующую 4ю колонку, соответственно оно "обернулось вокруг" и встало в первую. Числа 8, 9, 22 относительно своего начального расположения подвинулись на 2 вправо во 2й и 3й итерации - вот они 022

Comment: Кстати вы можете просто взять массив из 27 чисел, скажем arr, заполнить его случайными, уникальными числами и массив колонок col[3][9]. воспользоватся моими циклами печати которые вместо печати скопируют для каждой итерации (переменная j) массив колонок `col[k][i]=arr[m]`, перемешать значения в пределах каждого из 3х подмассивов col и напечатать их. При отгадывании по формуле считаете позицию и выводите число из arr[_число_]

Comment: Был такой фокус с картами:)